# git pull changes into a specific directory

Tags: git, github, git-pull

I am preparing a deployment automation script to deploy Drupal project in a Linux system. On Staging the branch is "Master" and I want to pull all the latest changes of "Release" branch to a specific directory and I want to rsync the changes to my web directory. I am trying to use the below command:

```
git -C /var/tmp/staging_12.21 pull
```

This command is not pulling the changed files into /var/tmp/staging_12.21 folder rather updates the .git file directly. Is there a way to download/pull only the latest changed files into a specific directory? Also staging_12.21 is an empty folder.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use Git as a deployment system as well as a version control system.  It isn't a deployment system, so this generally does not work well.  It does work well as a *version control* system.

> Is there a way to download/pull only the latest changed files ...

Not with Git, no.  Git's version control works with *commits*, not files.  The `git fetch` command downloads new *commits*.  The `git merge` and `git rebase` commands incorporate new commits into some existing repository, and the `git pull` command is a convenience command that first runs `git fetch`, then runs either `git merge` or `git rebase` (depending on how you instruct it) to combine the new commits with your own work.  (If you are not doing your own work, this can be pressed into service *as* a poor-man's deployment system, though it's definitely overkill and probably not a good idea.)

> Also staging_12.21 is an empty folder.

An empty folder is not particularly useful, except perhaps as a receptacle for an operation such as "extract some or all files from a commit".  Remember that a commit is a two-part entity, consisting of:

- a (compressed and read-only) snapshot of all files, as of the state they had at the time whoever made the commit, made it; and
- metadata *about* the commit, such as who made it, when, and the hash IDs of some set of *earlier* commits.

Because a commit is a snapshot of *all* files, it's always possible to extract some or all files from that commit, if you have it.

Because a commit is a *snapshot*, it has no "changes".  (Exercise: [here is a photo of Paris in 1920](https://www.artmajeur.com/medias/standard/t/i/titovilla/artwork/10187083_paris-b-300.jpg).  Click on it, take a look, and tell me what's changed.  What other information do I need to give you?  What do I even mean by *changed* in the first place?  Do I mean since 1919?)

If you have a full repository, which by definition has *every* snapshot, *and* you know which snapshot you have deployed in some location, you can use Git to *compare* the *deployed* snapshot with some other snapshot.  That will give you the information you seek.  You can use this to build a list of changed files, and then extract those from the snapshot you'd like to have deployed.  Note that you'll need to know which commit is *currently* deployed, and what is deployed had better actually match that commit.  It may be simpler to just extract the entire commit and make a whole new deployment from that.